# Is multiBinding supported in Windows phone silverlight 8.1

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, multibinding

I'm trying to figure out how to multibinding in Windows phone silverlight 8.1. I see a decent amount of posts about how mulibinding is supported in this silverlight version but not that silverlight version, but no information on what silverlight version 8.1 is.

So my question is, Can I multibind(without getting too hackish) in windows phone silverlight 8.1, and/or what version of silverlight is in windows 8.1?

Answer (score 1):

No Silverlight version does support `Multibinding`. All solutions you can find are custom solutions.